# Some "local to window" settings are being reset in Vim

Tags: vim-windows

I added `:set numberwidth=2` in my vimrc, but this value is always returned to `4` inside my windows.

It seems I need to use some autocommand to always force this value back to `2`.

In fact, even more alarming: when I force a short file to `:set numberwidth=2` manually (to regain two columns of space), once I do ANYTHING at this point, it reverts. Switch window/tab/buffer, enter insert mode (!), you name it. I can move the cursor without it reverting, however. The same behavior is seen with other window-local settings I've tried such as `relativenumber`. So I suspect perhaps some plugin might be culpable. But how to debug this?

1. I would like to not use an autocommand to do this if necessary
2. I would like to know what are the various things triggering this to reset to the default
3. If I really do must use an autocommand to do this, which autocommand should I use?

Comment: Thanks, not sure if i should delete. Clearly this behavior is not intended behavior so I just need to debug it now.

Comment: Don't delete. Debug and find out, and if you do find something, please post an answer.

Comment: I am doing it now. Its caused by one of my 40 or so plugins, I am just having trouble keeping track of my manual binary searching.

Comment: Forty freaking plugins…

Comment: @romainl I counted them the proper way and it's actually 51 plugins ([2400 or so lines](https://github.com/unphased/vim-config/blob/master/.vimrc))

Comment: Fifty one freaking plugins…

Comment: When I think that I found my 15 plug-ins were too much and I should remove some...

Answer (score 4):

The offending plugin is `jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle`.

I'll go drop a note on the Github now, and try to debug it.

Update: It's plain to see that the autocommands are being set very promiscuously. I never use this plugin anyway. I'm ditching the plugin obviously, and going to drop a note on the issues.

Comment: I have seen your issue on github. Probably that plugin should have used `augroups` to set the triggers etc. Let's see if it gets fixed.